# MUI X Charts SparkLine: How to remove the warning coming for xAxis value

Tags: javascript, reactjs, charts, mui-x, mui-x-charts

I am using MUI X Charts `<SparkLineChart>` to display 8 quarters of data as shown below,

```
import * as React from 'react';
import Stack from '@mui/material/Stack';
import Box from '@mui/material/Box';
import { SparkLineChart } from '@mui/x-charts/SparkLineChart';

export default function BasicSparkLineCustomization() {

  return (
    <Stack direction="column" sx={{ width: '100%' }}>
      <Stack direction="row" sx={{ width: '100%' }}>
        <Box sx={{ flexGrow: 1 }}>
          <SparkLineChart
            data={[10, 20, 15, 45, 44, 12, 55, 20]}
            xAxis={{
              scaleType: 'band',
              data: ['Q1', 'Q2', 'Q3', 'Q4', 'Q5', 'Q6', 'Q7', 'Q8'],
            }}
            height={50}
            width={150}
            showHighlight
            showTooltip
          />
        </Box>
      </Stack>
    </Stack>
  );
}
```

Whenever I hove my cursor on top of the chart showing the tooltip, I am getting this warning in my console.
[image]

https://stackblitz.com/run?file=Demo.js

I am not sure what am I doing wrong here.
Any help is much appreciated.

Thanks,

Comment: This warning seems to appear even in their default examples.

Comment: yes, is there a work around to remove this ?

Answer (score 1):

The data prop only expects number[], but you passed string[], try only passing numbers to it.

Comment: This warning comes even with passing numbers as well. but with a different message as "Warning: Failed prop type: Invalid prop `axis.scaleType` of value `band` supplied to `DefaultChartsAxisTooltipContent`, expected one of ["time"]"